# Neural network with tensorflow: fitting NN while optimizing custom function

Tags: optimization

I’m trying to find a way to create a NN with some layers and some neurons per layer and at the end I should have 4 output variables (2 bool and 2 double) and those 4 variables will be injected in an external function that will compute me a value (double) that I want to maximize.

So I have to compute the final value every time I have the 4 values.

And the goal is to fit the NN in order to maximize an externally computed value.

How could I do that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi bogdy, your question seems broad and mostly lacking of examples. Could you provide what you tried with some code snippets? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I didn’t code something like this for the moment, I didn’t find any way of maximizing a given function. 

Actually I want to create the NN from scratch using tensorflow. I already found how to create layers, specify the activation and give the number of neurons for each layer but then every example I found minimizes a loss function so that is not what I want...

Comment: It’s about a time serie. I want to give the NN the last known values of the time series and some other observations and then ask it to make a decision (characterized by the 4 values). From that decision I’ll get a double value and for every set of X (=Observations and values of time series) I’ll need to fit the model in order to have the greatest output values